# Real Analysis. Is my proof okay? Show that the Cantor set is totally disconnected in R, i.e. it contains no subset that is connected.

Tags: real-analysis

I like the $|x-y| >3^{-n}$ proof for this, but also wonder whether my proof below is acceptable.

proof: Assume that the Cantor set $P$ is not totally disconnected. i.e. it contains a subset $S$ that is connected.

Since S is bounded, by the least upper bound property (and also g.l.b.p), $a = inf(S)$ and $b=sup(S)$ exist. Since S is connected, the interval $(a,b)\subset S$. So $S$ contains an interval and thus $P$ contains an interval. Contradiction.

[My proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jLXj.jpg)

Comment: Well, you assume that P contains no interval subset, which seems to be exactly what you want to show, meaning your reasoning is circular here.

Comment: @RobBland That depends. You can "know" that the cantor set contains no intervals and still "not know" that it is totally disconnected. The crucial part is that while the intervals are the only connected subsets of the real line, that's not the definition of connected.

Comment: @Arthur Re: "that's not the definition of connected" - I think by Rudin theorem 2.47 "A subset $E$ of $R^1$ is connected iff it has the following property: If $x\in E, y\in E$, and $x<z<y$, then $z\in E$", we can say $(a,b) \subset S$, right?

Comment: @Xward Note that that's a theorem, though, not a definition.